# Combine columns with NAs to the new column and attach it existing df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with few columns, and head of specific two columns looks as follows (there are few thousands rows in total):

```
  corprsd1 corprsd2
2        1       NA
3       NA        0
4       NA        0
5        1       NA
6        1       NA
7       NA        0
```

Since for each row NAs in one column always correspond to 0 or 1 in the second column, I'd like to combine these rows into 1 and attach it to current dataframe, to get something like that:

```
  corprsd1 corprsd2 corcombined
2        1       NA       1
3       NA        0       0
4       NA        0       0
5        1       NA       1
6        1       NA       1
7       NA        0       0
```

I guess it can be done either by loop or some specific function - can you please tip me with the best solution? 
I guess that some function would be fastest, but looping should be more flexible (i.e. I could change condition upon which columns are combined).

Comment: Check out `?rowSums` and use `na.rm=TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
df <- data.frame(
  corprsd1 = c(1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA),
  corprsd2 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0)
)

df$combined <- rowSums(df, na.rm = T)
```

Which produces the expected output:

```
  corprsd1 corprsd2 combined
1        1       NA        1
2       NA        0        0
3       NA        0        0
4        1       NA        1
5        1       NA        1
6       NA        0        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for this. It would be faster simply to use `is.na` and `rowSums`.

```
corprsd1 <- c(1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA)
corprsd2 <- c(NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0)
table <- cbind(corprsd1, corprsd2)     # generate your original table without the rownames of 2:7
table[is.na(table)] <- 0     # replace NAs with 0s
table2 <- cbind(table, rowSums(table))     # generates new table with rowSums
colnames(table2) <- c("corprsd1", "corprsd2", "corcombined")
rownames(table2) <- c(2:7)
table2
```

Which produces

```
  corprsd1 corprsd2 corcombined
2        1       NA           1
3       NA        0           0
4       NA        0           0
5        1       NA           1
6        1       NA           1
7       NA        0           0
```

Comment: Yup, actually this single line does the job too:
p1$corpress <- rowSums(p1[,17:18], na.rm=TRUE)